# Fill GridViewColumn with c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a GridView with a column that needs to be filled with an algorithm. This algorithm uses a value from a SQL database.
How can I use a value from a sql database in an algorithm and than put the result in the GridView column. I have a connection with the database in ASP, but did not manage to do this yet in the code-behind (C#).
And what type of field should I use (boudfield, templatefield etc.)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If this particular algorithm isn't something that you can implement using SQL and incorporate into the data source, then my first inclination would be a TemplateField with a Hyperlink, LinkButton, Label, Literal...(whatever you want to hold the actual value).

Possible example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExample" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsExample">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="litAlgorithmResult" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# DoMyFunction(Eval("DataSourceField1").ToString(), Eval("DataSourceField2").ToString(), Eval("DataSourceField3").ToString()) %>'>
                </asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In your codebehind, add something like this (assuming VB.NET for some reason):

```
Protected Function DoMyFunction(ByVal Value1 as String, ByVal Value2 as String, ByVal Value3 as String) as String
    DoMyFunction = Value1 & Value2 & Value3
End Function
```

EDIT: Added several columns being passed to that function, and added an example function.

EDIT2: Added full example GridView.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. But I still haven't found out how to put in several variables at a time (3 columns from the SQL database). And I also didn't manage to write a function with the correct syntax :(

Comment: I added a full GridView for you - the key point to all of this is that you can call a function from the markup to do whatever you need to do and display it in the GridView.