# DataSet - Apply conditioning format of the entire column?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

Is there a way to apply conditioning format to an entire column from a DataSet? For example, here's the result from the dataset:

`ID FullName Number`

`1 Testing 0`

`2 More Test [null]`

`3 Last Test 1`

I would like to be able to format the `Number` column, if it's `0` then I would display empty string, if it's `null` then I would display `NR`, and if it's `1`, then I would display `T`.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the output data?  A little more context would be helpful in determining a good solution for this.  There are many different ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: Hi Steve, I'm exporting this data to text/excel file. Thanks.

Comment: @Saxman - what are you using to export the data, and does it support any kind of formatting on export?

Comment: It doesn't support formatting on support. And I just want to manipulate the data formatting, as well as some of the data before it gets exported. I guess I can just loop through the rows/columns one by one. I was hoping for an easier/faster way.

Comment: @Saxman: are you exporting this through a grid control?

Comment: I'm doing it manually, not through any control. For now what I did was manually looping through each row and column as you can see from my other post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've loop through the DataSet to make it work. Not sure if it's the best way though:

```
for(int i = 0; i< ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        var columnName = ds.Tables[0].Columns[j].ColumnName;
        if(columnName == "Number")
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][columnName] = SpecialFormat(columnName, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]));
        }
    }
}

private string SpecialFormat(string column, DataRow dataRow)
{
    string value = dataRow[column].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        if (value == "0")
            return "";
        if (value == "1")
            return "T";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It all really depends on how you're using the DataSet/DataTable - is this the DataSource for a GridView or FormView, and you just want to provide different output data on databinding?  Or do you want to go in and actually change the data present in the DataSet?

If it's the former, here's a basic GridView example of how to have a function execute during databinding to provide a different value (see [Fill GridViewColumn with c# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951926/fill-gridviewcolumn-with-c-code/5952136#5952136) for a VB.NET example):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExample" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsExample">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header Text">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="litFunctionResult" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# DoMyFunction(Eval("DataSourceField1") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And in your codebehind, add something like this:

```
Protected String DoMyFunction(Object field)
{
    int retValue;
    if (field == System.DBNull.Value)
        retValue = "NR";
    else if (Convert.ToInt32(field) == 0)
        retValue = "";
    else if (Convert.ToInt32(field) == 1)
        retValue = "T";
    else
        retValue = "uhoh?";

    return retValue;
}
```

EDIT: With the introduction of the fact that you're exporting this to Excel...this is probably not particularly handy.  Also, you didn't specify ASP.NET, so...unless you want to create and databind a GridView for some reason, this is useless.  I'll leave the answer here in case someone happens upon it.

Comment: I want to change the data that got returned to export to a file, not binding to gridview or anything. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should change the data _when_ you export to the file.

Answer (score 0):

DataSets don't have formats. They just contain data. If you need to "format" it, then you're using the wrong tool.

Comment: I'm not formatting the DataSet. I'm formatting the data coming out from the dataset.

Comment: That's not what your question says: "Is there a way to apply conditioning format to an entire column from a DataSet?"

Comment: I'm actually kind of with John on this one, but given your limitations, you may have no other option.  Typically the formatting and presentation is separated from the data, but since you're exporting a spreadsheet, unless you want to manually go and edit that spreadsheet, you've got to do it to the DataSet.